# Why is the Media Play/Pause key interpreted as the "G" key by some applications?

Tags: windows, keyboard, key-codes

When pressing the play/pause button on my Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600, I noticed that it sends a "G" keypress to certain applications (mostly games, I first noticed it in Lethal Company). After some googling, I found that it's a widespread issue, with people posting about it affecting games from [War Thunder](https://www.reddit.com/r/Warthunder/comments/zwv6gq/media_playpause_is_linked_to_g_key/) to [Halo MCC](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/p3f68m/media_keys_throwing_grenades_in_mcc/) to [CSGO](https://www.reddit.com/r/G502MasterRace/comments/46epgj/when_clicking_play_music_buttong4_in_csgo_it/). With how this affects such a wide variety of software I would think that it was an issue with an underlying API that they all use. I took a look at the [win32 keyboard API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), but that shows that there's a distinct keycode for the VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, separate from the "G" key.

Why is the Media Play/Pause key misinterpreted by these applications as the "G" key, and can anything be done to fix it?

Comment: Hello, did you verify what key code is sent in any shape or form? E.g. with AutoHotkey

Comment: @Destroy666 I've just been pressing the Play/Pause button on my keyboard, but people have reported the same issue with AHK. The AHK code is "Media_Play_Pause", which appears to map to the [VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/2a836cf2815ec947f70b18df3b79699a9dcf92e9/source/globaldata.cpp#L416) key code, which is [defined as 0xB3](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/2a836cf2815ec947f70b18df3b79699a9dcf92e9/source/keyboard_mouse.h#L45).

Comment: Does it happen when booting into Safe mode?